# How can i filter a resource and it's nested resources in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, scope, find

I have categories and each category has resources that belong to them. I want to use a scope on all categories and a different scope on their resources.

This is an example of what i am trying to do:

```
categories = Category.find_all_by_name('something').resources.find_all_by_resource_type_id(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

your post ain't exactly crystal clear

my guess is that you probably want the categories that have "something" name, and their resources eager-loaded. for that use this:

```
Category.where(:name => 'something').includes(:resources)
```

or, if you want to specify what resources you want for those "something" categories, you can use this:

```
Category.includes(:resources).where(:name => 'something', :resources => {:resource_type_id => 3})
```

more info about [active record querying, here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: The only problem is that i am trying to narrow the category resources down with cancan so i need to apply .accessible_by(current_ability) and other scopes to the category resources.